# rgb coloring fails in chrome and firefox

Tags: html

I was creating a simple testpage for myself, in which I've encountered a surprising bug. Firefox and chrome fail to correctly parse "rgb" coloring attribute. I know using "bg_color" is deprecated and I know it's always better to use "#code" but now I'm wondering what's causing this problem. I've also checked and apparently IE doesn't have such a bug. or maybe I'm doing something wrong? this code will result in dark blue bg color in chrome and FF.

```
<html>
<body>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">January</td>
    <td bgcolor="rgb(0,255,0)">$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

sidenote: browsers should support rgb as written in [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_bgcolor.asp)

Comment: See: http://w3fools.com/. Also, the w3schools article refers to the `background-color` CSS property. Only hexadecimal notation (and I believe it should be without the `#`) is allowed in `bgcolor`. Not that you should be using it anyway, as you said.

Comment: Why would anyone care about this bug when you can just use CSS instead?

Comment: @robertc since I'm developing an app, and I'm just using html to create a tidy logfile!

Comment: @Gajet A better solution would still be to use HTML/CSS - or possibly XML/XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML attributes are not the same thing as CSS.  The rgb() notation is CSS-only, and doesn't work in `bgcolor` or `color` attributes.

You can use CSS *in* an attribute, however - specifically the `style` attribute, if you don't want to generate stylesheets:

```
<td style="background-color: rgb(0,255,0)">
```